# Play Framework 2 - Different views for different devices

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm building a Play 2.1.0 (Java) app that needs to have 2 different versions: a desktop web app and a mobile web app. I'm looking for a way that doesn't modify the controllers' logic, but relies on the routing. The ideal behaviour should be:

- Routes are the same for desktop and mobile
- Controllers are the same for desktop and mobile
- Views are different for mobile and desktop, but share a naming convention.

Is there somewhere I can hookup with the routing behaviour and, say, append a .mob to the view name so the rendered view is `main.scala.html` for desktop and `main.scala.mob.html` for mobile? This would be ideal, since the controllers need no changes (or ugly ifs) and each view needs to have it's own mobile version. I guess I will need the request at this point to perform device detection. Even cooler if it could fallback to the desktop view if no mobile view was implemented for a specific action.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Gonzalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up composing the actions that needed a mobile version with another action. To achieve that, I created a `@Mobile` runtime annotation I used to annotate these actions with the name of the mobile view. All annotated actions will be composed with the following `MobileAction`, which performs device detection:

```
public class MobileAction extends Action<Mobile> {
    public MobileAction() {
    }

    public MobileAction(Mobile configuration, Action<?> delegate) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        final Http.Request request = ctx.request();
        final String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");

        // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent
        if (userAgent.contains("Mobi")) {
            ctx.args.put("viewName", configuration.value());
        }

        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

The I implemented a `DynamicRendered` class which looks for a `viewName` argument (optionally injected by `@Mobile`) and uses reflection to render the appropriate view.

```
public class DynamicRenderer {

    public static Html render(String viewName, Object... args) {
        final Map<String, Object> ctxArgs = Http.Context.current().args;
        final String view = ctxArgs.containsKey("viewName") ? ((String) ctxArgs.get("viewName")) : viewName;

        // Get argument classes
        final Class[] argClasses = new Class[args.length];
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            argClasses[i] = args[i].getClass();
        }

        try {
            // Get view render method and invoke
            final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(view);
            final Method render = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("render", argClasses);
            final Html html = ((Html) render.invoke(null, args));

            return html;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of calling `ok(viewName.render(...))` in the controller, I call `ok(DynamicRenderer.render("viewName", ...))`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is to use a CSS + JS styling library such as Foundation 5, or Bootstrap. Those can allow you to specify how your view should display in different screen sizes, by using css tags in your generated html. Lookup Foundation docs, they explain how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, but views will be totally different. So a CSS + JS solution won't be enough.

Comment: Up to you...just FYI Foundation does have the ability to dynamically hide/display certain parts of your UI based on the screensize... if you wanna go with rendering everything to HTML and then displaying only whats needed. Take a look here if you got 5 spare minutes: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html

Comment: I voted this up. Today I had the same task to make my views look ok on both desktop, tablet and mobile screens. I solved the problem with help of Bootstrap 3.3.6 and its responsive utilities.
Don't know why this answer was downvoted by someone, but actually the advice was good in 2014 and is even better in 2016 when Boostrap has evolved its responsive tooling.